# Receptacles and lights not working

Tags: electrical, receptacle

My daughter plugged in her cellphone charger and 4 120v lights immediately went out.i checked receptacle for voltage and found none. I pulled out receptacle and found no problems. 1 receptacle on this circuit is switched but the aforementioned one is not.I checked and reset all gfcis.Not sure which breaker is for this circuit so I carefully reset all of them twice.Pulled off breaker box cover and checked all wires for tightness.Removed switch for lights and direct wired it and got no voltage or light. The house is 20 years old with Romeo wire. All of this is on 12g wire which surprised me.I have spent 4 afternoons on this pulling out almost all switches and receptacles on first floor and garage in the surrounding area and checked everything with a meter and I can't find the problem. It blows my mind that this even happened.what could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Are these receptacles side-wired or backstabbed?

Comment: That is to say, we're after this distinction: https://www.handymanhowto.com/electrical-outlets-side-wire-versus-back-wire/   Also you would be better off spending your time mapping your electrical system, i.e. Learning which loads are on which breaker, so you know which breaker this is on, or at least, which breakers it is not on.

Comment: They are all side-wired except for one oddity I found. At some point built in shelves were added across one whole end of the room with cabinets at the bottom. There is a 1" gap between the back of the cabinet and the original wall where thru a small access hole they used wires from an existing outlet and basically moved the outlet to the back of the cabinet with 12g wire and came off new outlet with 2 (14g)  wires to feed a switch, 4 accent lights and an outlet at far end of shelves. I believe an original outlet is buried behind shelves. I now know which breaker controls all these outlets.